# WIEngine SpriteBatchNode Add

Tags: android, sprite, texture2d

I am developing a game in which i have to use the Sprites with the help of SpriteBatchNode

How to use SpriteBatch Node in WiEngine?

```
SpriteBatchNode  m_batchNode = SpriteBatchNode.make(Texture2D.makePNG(R.drawable.grossini_dance_atlas));
addChild(m_batchNode);
```

I used the following code.
i also need SpriteEx implementation with SpriteBatchNode

Answer (score 0):

you can use following code snippet

```
SpriteBatchNode  m_batchNode = SpriteBatchNode.make(Texture2D.makePNG(R.drawable.grossini_dance_atlas));
addChild(m_batchNode);

  SpriteEx sprite = SpriteEx.make(m_batchNode, WYRect.make(x, y, ITEM_WIDTH, ITEM_HEIGHT));
            sprite.setFlipX(random.nextBoolean());
            sprite.setFlipY(random.nextBoolean());
            sprite.setRotation(random.nextFloat() * 360f);
            sprite.setAutoFit(true);
            sprite.setContentSize(random.nextFloat() * 200 + 50, random.nextFloat() * 200 + 50);
            sprite.setPosition(pos.x, pos.y);
```